# uniting columns in dataframes in a list and renaming the last column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lapply, purrr

I have this list:

```
list1 <- list(`1` = structure(list(first_name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "D", "D"), name = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"2"), value = c("DGDGH", "DGDGH", "DGDGH", "DGDGH", "DGDGH", 
"DGDGH", "DGDGH", "DGDGH")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), `2` = structure(list(second_name = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"), name = c("1", "2", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2"), value = c("XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", 
"XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), `3` = structure(list(
    third_name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"), name = c("1", 
    "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2"), value = c("XCHDF", "XCHDF", 
    "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)))
```

I want to unite the first two columns and rename the third column with the column name of the fist column of `list1` like so:

```
final_list <- list(`1` = structure(list(id = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", 
"C2", "D1", "D2"), first_name = c("DGDGH", "DGDGH", "DGDGH", 
"DGDGH", "DGDGH", "DGDGH", "DGDGH", "DGDGH")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), `2` = structure(list(
    id = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2", "D1", "D2"), second_name = c("XCHDF", 
    "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L)), `3` = structure(list(id = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", 
"C2", "D1", "D2"), third_name = c("XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", 
"XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF", "XCHDF")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)))
```

Can someone please show me how this can be done using the `tidyverse` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the data frames in a list, you could make a function like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_func <- function(df) {
  nm <- colnames(df)[1]
  df %>%
    mutate(id = paste0(.[[1]], .[[2]])) %>%
    rename(old_first = 1,
           !!nm := 3) %>%
    select(4, 3)
}

glimpse(lapply(list1, my_func))
#> List of 3
#>  $ 1: tibble [8 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id        : chr [1:8] "A1" "A2" "B1" "B2" ...
#>   ..$ first_name: chr [1:8] "DGDGH" "DGDGH" "DGDGH" "DGDGH" ...
#>  $ 2: tibble [8 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id         : chr [1:8] "A1" "A2" "B1" "B2" ...
#>   ..$ second_name: chr [1:8] "XCHDF" "XCHDF" "XCHDF" "XCHDF" ...
#>  $ 3: tibble [8 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id        : chr [1:8] "A1" "A2" "B1" "B2" ...
#>   ..$ third_name: chr [1:8] "XCHDF" "XCHDF" "XCHDF" "XCHDF" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>